# typo3 cannot connect to the backend: server error

Tags: typo3

This is a typo3 4.6 installation that has been running relatively smoothly over the years and that presents a new error after a user with admin privileges has created a news item:

While the front-end works fine, it's suddenly not possible to connect to the backend. Instead the browser receives a error 500 page.

However, the apache error log does not show any error pertaining to typo3 or general PHP errors.

Trying to connect to the install tool gives the same 'server error' page and still no special entry in apache's error log.

I tried to use the command line tool 'typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh lowlevel_cleaner' but it results in this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PATH_tslibclass.tslib_pibase.php' ... in ... t3lib/class.t3lib_dev.php
```

I am not sure the cli_dispatch.phpsh is related and I generally don't use that command line tool.

I'm running out of options and any help or tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to login into database and check `sys_log` table, maybe there will be some hint (`order by uid desc` to check newest first) make sure there's enough disk space on the host, make sure that source files of TYPO3 aren't corrupted, you can remove content of `typo3temp` folder and `typo3conf/temp_*` files as well, anyway as you don't know the reason of problem it's hard to guess what may happen to FE :/ If it's possible make a copy of your instance at the other machine (the same PHP, MySQL, files etc) and try to reproduce problem locally

Comment: Of course first of all make sure that there's backup of the site available for you (files/database) and create one if isn't

Comment: Manually deleting typo3temp/* worked! 
Maybe you could make an answer with so that I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: You should delete typo3temp/Cache content not typo3temp content

Answer (score 0):

Glad that suggest helped you, for others there are several typical steps you can try:

- Check the `sys_log` table in your DB, maybe you'll find some hint.
- Enable better error reporting, even by changing `index.php` file manually.
- Delete content of `typo3temp` folder (but not folder itself)
- Delete `typo3conf/temp_*.php` files
- Make sure that there's enough space according to your limits - for an example check if file like `typo3conf/deprecation_xxxxxxx.log` didn't grow to size of several GB (actually it should be disabled in production at all).

Of course it's good idea to backup all files before you'll start to edit/delete anything. As you don't know what is the reason it's hard to guess what may happen when you'll delete caches - for an instance FE may stop to work as well.